# Javascript Printing variables to console in file as opposed to in function

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file where I initialize this variable:

```
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
```

in file scope. I then try to print it to console on the next line:

```
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
console.log($(".background").length);
```

But this always prints 0. When I print the same variable in a function I get 3:

```
function parallaxScroll(evt) {

    console.log($(".background").length);
    ...
```

Why are the values different from file scope to function scope?

Comment: `setInterval(function() {console.log($(".background").length)}, 100)`

Comment: Make sure that the `parallaxScroll` function is running after the document ready.

Comment: Clearly the number of elements found by that selector changes in that time.

Comment: @MuhammadAref So the parallax scroll function's value is correct, it's the file scope console log that prints 0 that's incorrect. From your comment I see that the html hasn't loaded yet while the JS is being executed. How can I guarantee it has loaded before I print the variable?

Comment: @Minimi: The `0` value is correct, because the elements the jQuery selector is looking for don't exist yet when that code executes.  You can put that code inside of a `document.ready` handler to wait until the entire DOM structure has loaded: `$(function() { /..your code../ });` (Which is shorthand for: `$(document).ready(function() { /..your code../ })`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are the values different from file scope to function scope?

It's not a question of "file scope" and "function scope", it's simply that the value is changing between the time you first execute the code and the time you next execute the code.

Specifically, this code:

```
$(".background")
```

When that selector queries the DOM the first time, it doesn't find anything.  So the number of results is `0`.  When you execute it again later, it does file matches.  So the number of results is `3` in this case.

It sounds like the first time you're executing the code is *before* the DOM structure has fully loaded.  So the elements you're looking for simply don't exist yet.  You can wait until the DOM structure is loaded and ready by using a `document.ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($(".background").length);
});
```

Or, shorter:

```
$(function () {
    console.log($(".background").length);
});
```